# What is the different between enter and return key in Mac 128K?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I saw the Mac 128K, and see that keyboard have return key and enter key. In the model mac only remain the return key. What is the different between these two keys in the old system? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carriage return (CR) causes a linebreak on Mac. Thus, `return` was (and is) a formatting key.

The enter key was used for other purposes as executing a shell command, for example.

Nowadays, one single key is used for both purposes.